# How to estimate this series (similar to harmonic series)

Tags: sequences-and-series

How to prove $$\frac{1}{2x+2}<\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{k-1}}{x+2k-1}<\frac{1}{2x},\ \forall\ x>0?$$

This is not a positive series, or else I could use integration method.

Answer (score 2):

You can sum a pair of terms to get all positive terms.  $$\frac 1{x+2k-1}-\frac 1{x+2k+1}=\frac{2}{(x+2k)^2-1}$$

Comment: Thank you...And if we use this, and use integration method, then some $\ln$ occurs...then??